# How to make index.php set path to /index.html

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I'm unfamiliar with php but I'm running a server locally on apache using XAMPP.

I want connecting to localhost to automatically set the path to localhost/index.html.

index.php looks as follows

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/some-directory');
    exit;
?>
Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(
```

My javascript has code which checks if the path is /index.html. This results in the website breaking. Manually typing localhost/index.html into my browser works but just typing localhost breaks the website.

I've tried adding /index.thml to the Location in header but it didn't work

```
header('Location: '.$uri.'/some-directory/index.html');
```

Comment: couldn't this be set up with .httpdocs?

Comment: @CemFirat Thanks for the comment. Turns out my apache config was pointing to a copy of the project not the actual one so changing index.php did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your index.php file routes requests to the /some-directory directory rather than the root directory.
Try this:

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/index.html');
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Turns out my apache config was pointing to a copy of the project not the actual one so changing index.php did nothing.